# Как вернуть значение нового массива в которые пришли данные?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
   let ticketArr = []
   
   //Пушу значения в масив 
   const pushToBucket = player  => {
         ticketArr.push(player)
         console.log('Updated ticketArr' , ticketArr) //здесь выводит обновленый массив
   }
  
  
   //нужно вывести новое значение ticketArr в console.log() , по задумке в масив будут приходить данные по клику пользователя
   console.log(ticketArr)    //Выведет пустой масив , а нужно вывести масив с новыми данными
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы получить массив с данными, нужно эти самые данные в этот массив записать.

В вашем случае, запись в массив производится внутри функции, значит данные для массива нужно передать сначала в функцию.

```
let ticketArr = [];


const pushToBucket = (player) => {
    ticketArr.push(player);
    console.log('Updated ticketArr', ticketArr);
};


pushToBucket('user');   // передаем в функцию "юзера"
console.log(ticketArr); // [ 'user' ]

pushToBucket('user2');  // передаем в функцию "второго юзера"
console.log(ticketArr); // [ 'user', 'user2' ]

pushToBucket('user3');  // передаем в функцию "третьего юзера"
console.log(ticketArr); // [ 'user', 'user2', 'user3' ]
```

Ну, либо я не совсем понял что именно вам нужно.

Comment: Не все так просто у меня функция pushToBucket висит на кнопке которая 

Там в чем штука : польователь нажимает на кнопку напротив нужного ему столбца 

Эти данные записываются в новый массив ticketArr

Теперь мне нужно взять часть этих данных и из них вывести/зарендерить в корзину (она на той же странице)

И у меня проблема , не получается зарендерить в корзину данные которые выбрал пользователь 

вот ссылка на песочницу (https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-framework-fgb5f?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Какую именно информацию в массив сохранить хотите?

Comment: Wherefrom, where, costforEconom, costForBiznes и еще сотрудники